# Can't access certain member variables after passing object to another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've a multithreaded application where an object A has an instance of a linked list B. After passing A to another thread, I can't access B.

Definition A:

```
struct Peer 
{
   public:
   ...
   Linked_List *message_list;
   ...
   Peer() {
      ...
      message_list = new Linked_List;
      ...
   };
 ...
};
```

Definition B:

```
class Linked_List {
public:
...
Linked_List();
int                 add(string);
string              get();
string              get_nb();
void                clear(bool);
private:
struct Node*        head;
HANDLE              ghSemaphoreLinkedList;
HANDLE              ghSemaphoreGet;
};
struct Node {
string data;
Node* next;
};
```

Main Thread:

```
Peer *client = new Peer;
CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) &SendToPeer, &client, 0, &thread);
```

Accessing Thread:

```
DWORD WINAPI SendToPeer(Peer *client)
{
while(1)
{
            //While debugging, VSC++ says it can't read the memory of  client->message_list
    string msg = client->message_list->get();
    }
}
```

What could be the problem?

Regards,
David

Comment: Does get return a member of Linked_List?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the `&` operator when passing the `client` variable to the `lpParameter` param of `CreateThread()`:

```
//CreateThread(..., &client, ...);
CreateThread(..., client, ...);
```

`SendToPeer()` is expecting to receive a `Peer*` pointer but you are actually sending it a `Peer**` pointer instead.

Comment: Thanks! client hasn't been a pointer until now and I totally forgot about this! Saved me hours! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you may only need to pass the pointer value to the function, and may be you should respect the void*, since the fourth param of CreateThread is LPVOID which is void*. I didn't test it, hope it will work

```
DWORD WINAPI SendToPeer(LPVOID param)
{
    Peer * client = (Peer*) param;
    while(1)
    {
            //While debugging, VSC++ says it can't read the memory of  client->message_list
           string msg = client->message_list->get();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
Peer *client = new Peer;
CreateThread(NULL, 0, &SendToPeer, client, 0, &thread);
```